# Determine the the swipe angle of a rotating circle.

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, convergence-acceleration

I have a circle rotating with the acceleration of $5000^{\circ}/s^{2}$  for time $0:T/2$; then $-5000^{\circ}/s^{2}$ for time $T/2:T$, and the velocity is $20^{\circ}/s$. How can I determine the swipe angle $d\theta/dt$?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.